# What Algorithm/Technique Can I Use to Spread Out Bots as Evenly as Possible?

Tags: algorithm, spacing

Trying to wrap my head around this but not able to come up with the algorithm. Maybe someone can help? The question is as follows:

*You’re writing part of the code for an online card game. In the game, players pass cards right and left around a table. In your online version, you want to allow users to set up a game with some number of human players and some number of “bot” (automated) players. In order to be fair, you want to spread out the bots as evenly as possible around the table; for example, if there are 6 total players and 3 are bots, every third seat should be a bot, and the rest should be humans.
Example
Input: "6 3"
Output "HHBHHBHHB"*

Basically given the input of "6 3" (where first number is number of humans and second number is number of bots) I need to return the seating arrangement that spaces out the bots as evenly as possible. "H" represents Human and "B" represents bots.

I can't think of the logic to implement this. I get a feeling it's embarrassingly simple but I'm drawing a blank. Can someone help please? Doesn't matter what coding language you use. I'm more interested in the algorithm and solution.

EDIT: Found out how to do it when Humans and Bots are nice numbers that divide into each other (Humans divided by bots: 9 and 3, 6 and 2, 10 and 5, etc.) but how about for any combination?

Example: Input "6 4"
You would think that the following will work:
HHBHHBHBHB

but that is not as evenly as possible. The following is the better solution:

HHBHBHHBHB

Comment: `round(9/6) == 2` + `3/3 == 1`... So, place 2 humans, place 1 bot. Repeat until you place all tiles. Or `6 + 3 == 9 places` `9/3 == 3` means a bot must be "every third seat" to be evenly distributed. And you fill the rest with humans

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am so sorry. I put the wrong input. Please see update. So instead of Input being "6 3" it should be "9 3". I just typed the wrong input by mistake but I have updated the problem now. Does that change your comment? I'm still not following how I can programmatically figure that out....Like what if the input was "12 4"? I know it means I can put the pattern of 3 humans and 1 bot like so: "HHHBHHHBHHHB" but how can I figure that out for any input? 12/4 is 3. Per your logic, if I understand correctly, it means every 3rd seat is a bot but that would be incorrect.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Sorry long day. Just looked at question again and the input was correct but still not following you. If my input is "12 4" that means 16 players total.

So if I am following you correctly that means`round(16/12)` === 1 + `4/4 === 1` ? Hopefully you can explain.

Comment: @OneCricketeer After manually typing it out I think I understand it now. I understood the second approach you took when you explained it as "`6 + 3 == 9 places` `9/3 == 3`". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic approach for any number of different classes of participants.  I decided to offer an example with (E)xperts, (H)umans and (B)ots.  It tries to be even no matter what.

It isn't perfectly optimal in the general case, but it is optimal in the simple case.

```
import random

def distribute (count_dict):
    total = sum(count_dict.values())
    freq = {}
    state = {}
    for key, count in count_dict.items():
        freq[key] = count/total
        state[key] = random.random() # Start randomly

    answer = []
    for i in range(total):
        best_state = -1
        best_key = None
        for key, cur_state in state.items():
            cur_state += freq[key]
            state[key] = cur_state

            if best_state < cur_state:
                best_state = cur_state
                best_key = key

        answer.append(best_key)
        state[best_key] -= 1

    return answer


print(distribute({"E": 3, "B": 7, "H": 11}))
```

Comment: Hi. I appreciate you providing a solution. I tried yours against the test case in the OP (6 humans and 3 bots) and the output was not correct. The bots aren't distributed to match the output in the test case. You can see on IDEOne: https://ideone.com/HJAcqo

Expected Output: HHBHHBHHB
Actual Output: 'H', 'B', 'H', 'H', 'B', 'H', 'H', 'B', 'H'

Comment: @Bmoe In other words it gave the expected solution, except with one person moved from the front to the back.  Given that the application distributes them "around the table", this is the same solution up to rotation.

Comment: I think it's just a flaw of the english language. I can see the way the problem is worded someone can assume a circle table but that's just an assumption right? "Around the table" can apply to other shapes of tables as well (ie. rectangles, squares, triangles, etc). I can see why the output is just the players output in a line so that we don't have to worry about the table type. The output given in the problem was there for a reason I think. If we could assume "wrap-around" they would have stated it.

Comment: @Bmoe If that is the wording of the question and the only answer that they accept, then they posed the question badly.  In fact the output you got was more fair than theirs because in mine no human is farther than any other from the nearest bot, while in theirs the first human is farther.